# Dynamic method calls in a Clojure macro?

Tags: clojure

I'm attempting to write a macro which will call java setter methods based on the arguments given to it.

So, for example:

```
(my-macro login-as-fred {"Username" "fred" "Password" "wilma"})
```

might expand to something like the following:

```
(doto (new MyClass)
  (.setUsername "fred")
  (.setPassword "wilma"))
```

How would you recommend tackling this?

Specifically, I'm having trouble working out the best way to construct the setter method name and have it interpreted it as a symbol by the macro.

Comment: Do you really want to call `doto` with a class as the first argument?  You're going to be doing things to the Class object itself rather than an instance of that class.

Comment: Ah, thanks - that was a typo. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The nice thing about macros is you don't actually have to dig into the classes or anything like that. You just have to write *code that generates the proper s-expressions*.

First a function to generate an s-expression like `(.setName 42)`

```
(defn make-call [name val]
  (list (symbol (str ".set" name) val)))
```

then a macro to generate the expressions and plug (~@) them into a `doto` expression.

```
(defmacro map-set [class things]
  `(doto ~class ~@(map make-call things))
```

Because it's a macro it never has to know what class the thing it's being called on is or even that the class on which it will be used exists.

Comment: Doesn't work.  For one thing you can't take the value of `.` like that.

Comment: fixed to include Brian Carper's changes

Answer (score 7):

Please don't construct s-expressions with `list` for macros. This will seriously hurt the hygiene of the macro. It is very easy to make a mistake, which is hard to track down. Please use always syntax-quote! *Although, this is not a problem in this case, it's good to get into the habit of using only syntax-quote!*

Depending on the source of your map, you might also consider to use keywords as keys to make it look more clojure-like. Here is my take:

```
(defmacro configure
  [object options]
  `(doto ~object
     ~@(map (fn [[property value]]
              (let [property (name property)
                    setter   (str ".set"
                                  (.toUpperCase (subs property 0 1))
                                  (subs property 1))]
                `(~(symbol setter) ~value)))
            options)))
```

This can then be used as:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(configure (MyClass.) {:username "fred" :password "wilma"}))
(clojure.core/doto (MyClass.) (.setUsername "fred") (.setPassword "wilma"))
```

Comment: I disagree. Using `list` can be dangerous if you don't understand what's going on, but if you restrict yourself to using only `syntax-quote` it is much easier to lose touch with how macros work internally, and believe that `syntax-quote` is the only macro-building tool.

One thing I *would* advise against is `(map (fn [[x y]] ...) coll)`; this is more cleanly expressed with `(for [[x y] coll] ...)`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use for often enough. However I stand to my opinion concerning list. It is easy to make a quote vs. backtick mistake. And it is done often enough in the wild. Even in clojure.core and contrib by people who sure know how macros work. syntax-quote simply eliminates a whole class of bugs. Always better than fixing after the fact.

Comment: Ok. "class of bugs" is maybe a bit much. But it makes symbol capture explicit instead of an accident.

Comment: You can easily enough use both: `(list \`first some-arg)`.

Comment: Yes. And it is easy to type `(list 'first some-arg)` instead, while it is unlikely to type `(~'first ~some-arg)` instead of `(first ~some-arg)`. Which is even shorter in this case. If you feel like it, use the `list` approach. But I would advise against it in 95% of the cases. (Imagine some backticks at the right places. I don't get the comment formatting.)

Comment: @kotarok SO uses \` to delimit code blocks, as I'm sure you know, so they can't appear "for real" either inside or outside a code segment - they would terminate it. The solution is a simple backslash-escape. I wrote my code as (bear with me - escaping in order to describe escaping is hard!) \`(list \\`first some-arg)\`, which comes nicely out to `(list \`first some-arg)`.

Comment: @amalloy Ah. I tried the markdown way which is not backslash, but triple backtick or so.

Answer (score 5):

Someone (I believe Arthur Ulfeldt) had an answer posted that was almost correct, but it's been deleted now.

This is a working version:

```
(defmacro set-all [obj m]
  `(doto ~obj ~@(map (fn [[k v]]
                       (list (symbol (str ".set" k)) v))
                     m)))

user> (macroexpand-1 '(set-all (java.util.Date.) {"Month" 0 "Date" 1 "Year" 2009}))
(clojure.core/doto (java.util.Date.) (.setMonth 0) (.setDate 1) (.setYear 2009))

user> (set-all (java.util.Date.) {"Month" 0 "Date" 1 "Year" 2009})
#<Date Fri Jan 01 14:15:51 PST 3909>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to bite the bullet and use `clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod` like this:

```
(defn do-stuff [obj m]
  (doseq [[k v] m]
    (let [method-name (str "set" k)]
      (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
        obj
        method-name
        (into-array Object [v]))))
   obj)

(do-stuff (java.util.Date.) {"Month" 2}) ; use it
```

No need for a macro (as far as I know, a macro would not allow to circumvent reflection, either; at least for the general case).

Comment: The macro does not circumvent reflection at lease not in spirit. it generates s-expressions blindly with out regard to the fact that they happen to reference classes.

Comment: Using reflection for this is pretty vile. Macros and reflection are both heavy tools that you should think twice before using, but if you can specify the fields to set as literals then macros seem far nicer.