# call setX method on java object to convert map to java object?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to convert JSON file to thrift binary format to save storage and network bandwidth. this is irrelevant to my question. But want to describe its context.

So let say, I have a `map` from json, and Java Class `Event`

```
(def m 
 {"a" 1 
  "b" 2})
```

java class

```
package my-test;

class Event {
   public String a;
   public String b;
   public void setA(String a) { this.a = a; }
   public void setB(String b) { this.b = b; }
}
```

How can I get a `Event` object with value `m`?

---

P.S.

tried to use `call-method*` mentioned in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/YJNRnGXLr2I

```
(defn call-method* [obj m & args]
  (eval `(. ~obj ~(symbol m) ~@args)))
```

but `Can't embed object in code, maybe print-dup not defined` raised. I have no idea why.

```
=> (def o (Event.))
=> (call-method* o "setA" "1")
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't embed object in code,  
maybe print-dup not defined: mytest.Event@681d891, compiling:   
 (/private/var/folders/hd/xxl2lfmn5wggspxwwtk2r2zr0000gn/T/form-init2883112335729429073.clj:1:1)
```

P.S.

This Question [Dynamic method calls in a Clojure macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1710970/262425) is more appropriate to read.

Comment: About thrift, I tried to set instance of `thrift generated java class` with clojure.java.data. It didn't worked with `clojure.java.data/to-java` because `thrift generated java class` is not a `bean` by default. `thrift --gen java:beans a.thrift` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

clojure.java.data/to-java worked.

```
(import 'mytest.Event)
(use 'clojure.java.data)
(def m {"a" "1"})
(println (bean (to-java Event m)))
```